# Is there a metric space structure on $\mathbb Z$ such that the open sets are the subsets $S\subset \mathbb Z$ such that $\mathbb Z-S$ is finite?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I really don't know how to go about answering this question.

$S$ is open if $\mathbb Z - S$ is finite. If $S$ is open then this also means that $\mathbb Z -S$ is closed. So, the closed sets are the finite sets. I recognize this as the finite complement topology. The open sets look like $\mathbb Z - \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ and all finite sets are closed.

But how does one define a metric given what the open sets are?

Comment: Where did you find this question? This is a topological space for sure, but I doubt if this is a metric space!

Comment: This is a sample UPenn prelim question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't finite, the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't Hausdorff, hence the space isn't metrisable.

Comment: Is this a theorem? Can I find it in Munkres?

Comment: @AlJebr It's not hard to show that all metric spaces are Hausdorff, and likewise that the finite complement topology on an infinite set is not Hausdorff. This is largely just looking at the definition.

Comment: Probably, you should definitely find the theorem which states that any metric space is Hausdorff in there, as for the finite complement topology on an infinite set not being Hausdorff, all you need to show is that any pair of open sets always have nonempty intersection.